# Arcsde and Oracle on same machine but while creating a Enterprise Geodatabase giving TNS Error

Tags: arcgis-desktop, enterprise-geodatabase, oracle-dbms, arcgis-10.2

I have Installed Arcgis Desktop 10.2 and Oracle 11G and Arcsde 10.2 and oracle Client

When I am Creating a Enterprise Geodatabase it is giving me this error:

ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
No extended error.
Failed to execute (CreateEnterpriseGeodatabase).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your RDBMS install is 64-bit, and your Client install is 32-bit, then the issue could be an incorrect or incomplete tnsnames.ora file in whichever was installed last.  I always make sure to propagate the same comprehensive tnsnames.ora to all my Oracle installs.  You can diagnose SQL*Net connection failures with 'tnsping' and/or google the ORA error and review the dozens of potential causes for this error.